# Output from subprocess.check_output does not show if subprocess throws exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I have 2 simple files.

**file1.py**

```
import subprocess

print("Going to run file1")
print(subprocess.check_output(["python", "file2.py"]).decode("utf-8"))
```

**file1.py**

```
print("\n\nHELLO WORLD\n\n")
raise Exception("FOO")
```

As is, when running file1.py, you will NOT see the "Hello World". If you remove the exception you will see the output.

Why is the print hidden when the exception is present?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider these facts:

- `check_output()` requires output to be captured, so it's not being sent direct to the TTY. Conequently, the content is only printed *later*, when `print()` is run.
- Exception handling happens *immediately when an exception is thrown*.
- `check_output()`, when the program being run fails, throws an exception immediately rather than returning. The function must either return a value, or throw an exception, it can not do both.
- When you run `a(b())`, `b` happens before `a`. In this context, `a` is `print()`, and `b` is `subprocess.check_output()`.

Given the above: When `subprocess.check_output()` throws an exception, that exception is handled before `print()` is started; so the content that `subprocess.check_output()` would has captured from the subprocess stdout never has a chance to be returned, much less printed.

---

Note that you *can* still retrieve the output: it's attached to the exception object.

```py
import subprocess

# original example couldn't be run by anyone except OP
#cmd = ['python', 'file2.py']

cmd = ['sh', '-c', 'echo "output"; exit 1']

try:
    print(subprocess.check_output(cmd))
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as ex:
    print(f'Unable to run process: emitted exit status {ex.returncode}')
    print(f'...after printing output {ex.output!r}')
```

However, if the only thing you're going to do with output is unconditionally print it, then consider not capturing it at all in the first place, and letting `file2.py` write to the terminal (or other inherited/original stdout destination) directly. To do that, just switch to `subprocess.run(cmd, check=True)` and skip the `print` entirely.